# Wald test in regression (OLS and GLMs): t- vs. z-distribution

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model

I understand that the Wald test for regression coefficients is based on the following property  that holds asymptotically (e.g. Wasserman (2006): [All of Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387402721), pages 153, 214-215):
$$
\frac{(\hat{\beta}-\beta_{0})}{\widehat{\operatorname{se}}(\hat{\beta})}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
Where $\hat{\beta}$ denotes the estimated regression coefficient, $\widehat{\operatorname{se}}(\hat{\beta})$ denotes the standard error of the regression coefficient and $\beta_{0}$ is the value of interest ($\beta_{0}$ is usually 0 to test whether the coefficient is significantly different from 0). So the size $\alpha$ Wald test is: reject $H_{0}$ when $|W|> z_{\alpha/2}$ where
$$
W=\frac{\hat{\beta}}{\widehat{\operatorname{se}}(\hat{\beta})}.
$$

But when you perform a linear regression with `lm` in R, a $t$-value instead of a $z$-value is used to test if the regression coefficients differ significantly from 0 (with `summary.lm`). Moreover, the output of `glm` in R sometimes gives $z$- and sometimes $t$-values as test statistics. Apparently, $z$-values are used when the dispersion parameter is assumed to be known and $t$-values are used when the dispersion parameter is esimated (see [this link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/100878.html)).

Could someone explain, why a $t$-distribution is sometimes used for a Wald test even though the ratio of the coefficient and its standard error is assumed to be distributed as standard normal?

**Edit after the question was answered**

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61292/21054) also provides useful information to the question.

Comment: What makes you think that the test statistic being reported is necessarily a Wald test?

Comment: Because the $z$- or $t$-values are always the coefficient divided by its standard error in `lm` and `glm`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The output from `glm` using a Poisson distribution gives a $z$-value because with a Poisson distribution, the mean and variance parameter are the same. In the Poisson model, you only have to estimate a single parameter ($\lambda$). In a `glm` where you have to estimate both a mean *and* dispersion parameter, you should see the $t$-distribution used.

For a standard linear regression, you assume the error term is normally distributed. Here, the variance parameter has to be estimated - hence the use of the $t$-distribution for the test statistic. If you somehow knew the population variance for the error term, you could use a $z$-test statistic instead.

As you mention in your post, the distribution of the test is asymptotically normal. The $t$-distribution is asymptotically normal, so in a large sample, the difference would be negligible.

Answer (score 4):

In the GLM framework, in general, the *W* test statistic you mentioned **is asymptotically** *Normal* distributed, that's why you see in R the *z* values.

In addition to that, when dealing with a linear model, i.e a GLM with a Normal distributed response variable, the distribution of test statistic **is** a *Student's t*, so in *R* you have *t* values.