# Why do GLMs use z-scores for parameter inference?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, inference, normality-assumption, z-statistic

Generalized Linear Models typically use z-scores for inference on parameters ($\beta$s) (see [here](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/regression/how-to/binary-logistic-regression/interpret-the-results/key-results/), for example).

This assumes that parameter estimates ($\hat{\beta}$s) follow a normal distribution? Why is this assumption typically made? The model errors are *usually* not normally distributed.

Is it just based on the central limit theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because GLM parameter estimates are maximum likelihood estimates, and those are asypmtotically normal if we assume the observations are independent. See [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture3.pdf), for instance. Note that this is only an asymptotic result so for a particular finite sample your test statistics won't be exactly normal.

Comment: That makes sense. So why don't we use the t-score since we don't have the true standard deviation of the model?

Comment: For those who may be interested, I found an answer to my question in the above comment here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60074/wald-test-for-logistic-regression under "When is a z and when a t value used?"