# Should I be using Z-tests or T-Tests for my scientific data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, z-test

I've conducted a survey for my thesis where I ask a series of questions of the format:

`A statement relating to the experiment`

Then the participants answer strongly disagree (1) --> strongly agree (5)

I have 14 responses and two groups, one control and one experimental (7) in each. With the answers to each of these questions, I have checked for statistical significance in each question by use of a Z-test, however I was reading this morning that my data may be *ordinal* and *small sample size*, in which case I should use a T-test.

Is my initial approach valid still?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85804/choosing-between-z-test-and-t-test or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61284/t-tests-vs-z-tests , but the more general question is if you should use *any* of those tests with this data.

Comment: Wouldn't fisher's exact test be a better fit here, since your answers are categorical and sample size is small?

Comment: I don't understand "one control and one experimental in each". Are you saying that controls and treatments are paired? Or did you randomly assign 14 people to two groups?

Comment: random assignment of people to two groups, so participants either did the experiment or the control.

Comment: Why would *ordinal data* suggest a t-test?

Comment: Echoing Glen_b 's response:  Your dependent variables are ordinal in nature, so you should use tests appropriate for ordinal responses.  Some you might look into:  Cochran-Armitage test (perfect for your case); Mann-Whitney test (common and simple, but some people don't think it should it be used for discrete data with many ties, like your Likert response data); ordinal regression (in some software packages, not as scary as it sounds, but might be overkill for what you need).  In any case, t-test or z-test are probably not appropriate.

Comment: HOW many respondents and how many question items do you have ?  What are your question items  and what are trying to estimate ? It seems your scoring  is  unjustified.