# Confidence intervals for mean correlation

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, fisher-transform

What is the correct way to define confidence intervals for the mean of multiple correlations? I understand how to calculate CIs for individual correlation coefficients, I also understand how to calculate the mean correlation through Fisher's transformation. But what are the confidence intervals for this mean correlation value?
Surely, it can not be just the +-(respective z-score of CI level) multiplied by SE of the final mean Fisher's transformed correlation score, since each single Fisher's transformed correlation score is constructed from multiple data and has it's own precision and SE.

Comment: This question raises two issues: first, what would the mean of a bunch of correlation coefficients estimate?  Second, how are these correlation coefficients related?  Are they independent or not; and if they are not independent, we need the details of how they are generated.  Typically the correlation coefficients estimated from a single multivariate dataset are strongly interdependent and it would be erroneous to work with them as if they were independent.

Comment: I wanted to keep the question simple, but I understand some clarification would be needed for a precise answer. My goal is to provide a simple yet convincing argument that in a correlation matrix of supposedly consistently correlated variables, certain cells contain higher correlation coefficients than different cells, on average.

Comment: For any such argument to be valid, it would need to appeal to how the data were collected and how their joint distribution is modeled.

Comment: If it helps, we are talking about Likert scale answers, range 1-6, on a one-factor psychological questionnaire with high internal consistency (all questions have similar content, factor loading, and are all moderately to strongly positively correlated, range circa 0.5 - 0.8).

Comment: That raises additional complications, because there is now the additional issue of what a correlation coefficient even means, given that these are just ordinal scales and not numerical ones.  It also suggests you are trying to solve some kind of unstated statistical problem with this averaging; and, because this averaging procedure is so unusual, you should forgive us for thinking there likely is a better solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: Understood, for now, I am perfectly happy with a conceptual explanation of the calculation of the confidence intervals of the mean correlation.

Comment: You speak about a correlation matrix, bit it is not entirely clear. Do you take a mean of multiple entries in the matrix or do you have multiple correlation matrixes and do you take the mean of the same entry for different matrices?

Comment: You speak about confidence intervals, but also about comparison between two means. That is a different thing as [this recent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497338/why-is-mean-%c2%b1-2sem-95-confidence-interval-overlapping-but-the-p-value-is-0) shows.

Comment: From your problem description it is not clear what the source of error is for the different correlation coefficients for which you want to compute the mean. If this is some questionnaire and you want to compute the mean of correlations observed in different people then these different people *might* be considered as different populations with different correlations from which you sample. You might be better of as computing the mean of correlations and use the variance between the correlations in the sample to estimate the error.

Comment: Because there are so many different ways to compute a mean and different ways to consider the problem, it is essential that you describe the details. There is no simple and general "conceptual explanation of the calculation of the confidence intervals of the mean correlation"

Comment: I see. Well, you're technically right. I do not need CIs per se, I only need SE, because then I can do various statistical tests and construct CIs additionally. I am quite satisfied with Eoin's suggestion, for now, and I will think about the problem more. But I am grateful for your comments, thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you describe is just fine.

If $\bf{x}$ $= [x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]$, your set of data points, is approximately normally distributed, $\text{mean}(x) \pm \alpha \times\text{se}(x)$ produces a valid confidence interval, with $\alpha \approx 1.96$ for a 95% CI. As you note, since correlation coefficients aren't typically normally distributed, you can transform them using the Fisher z-transformation, calculated the mean and CI of the transformed values, and then back-transform to the original scale.

You're right that this is throwing away information: each of the coefficients has a different mean and SE, and you could obtain a better estimate by giving more weight to the more precisely-estimated correlations. This can be done, for instance, by fitting a multilevel model. However, the simple approach still yields calibrated confidence intervals.

The same thing happens when you want to calculate confidence intervals for a grand mean (a mean of means), for instance when you have multiple data points per group, and want to calculate a mean across groups.

---

Update: It's just occurred to me that you could, comments about the assumptions of your analysis notwithstanding, reframe this problem as a linear mixed model.

Let's say you currently have $n$ independent variables, $\bf x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, and $n$ dependant variables $\bf y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n$, and you're currently calculating $n$ correlation coefficients, $r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n$. As noted in the comments, I assume you believe that these correlations are independently sampled from a common distribution, and you're interested in calculating the mean and standard error of that distribution, for instance that you've collected $x$ and $y$ for each of the $n$ participants in an experiment, calculated $r$ for each participant, and wish to estimate $r$ at the population level.

This can be recast as a linear mixed model

$$y_i = \alpha_p + \beta_p x_i$$

where $\alpha_p$ and $\beta_p$ are the intercept and slope term
for participant $p$, and $\alpha_p \sim \text{Normal}(A, \sigma_A)$, $\beta_p \sim \text{Normal}(B, \sigma_B)$.
You're interested in estimating $B$, the population-level
fixed effect for the slope parameter.

This can be done easily using `lme4` by pivoting your data to a long format with one row per observation and columns for `x`, `y`, and `participant`, and using the command

```
lmer(y ~ 1 + x + (1 + x|participant), data=your_long_data)
```

Good luck!

Comment: "each of the coefficients has a different mean and SE, and you could obtain a better estimate by giving more weight to the more precisely-estimated correlations" This is more specifically only the case when the assumption is that all the correlations are sampled from the same distribution. To me it is not clear whether this is the situation in this question.

Comment: Surely if they're calculating the mean correlation, and the standard error of the mean, they're already assuming that the correlations are sampled from the same distribution?

Comment: For me that is not sure. It could also be the mean of correlation coefficients for entirely different populations, or the mean of correlation coefficients which are different due to a random effect. If the different correlation coefficients are really considered to be the same then it would definitely be important to apply different weights in computing the mean and using the plain mean as you suggest in the first paragraph would be a bad advise for general situations.

Comment: This answer seems to assume all the correlation coefficient estimates are independent.

Comment: It is the amount of precision I am losing I am interested in. I fear that when we construct CIs around mean correlation with this simple approach, the CIs would be quite wider than they should be. Because, here N = number of correlations, and it's relatively small compared to N = number of observation per variable, which is usually much higher and which we use to construct CIs around single correlation. But it is just my feeling and I might be wrong.

Comment: As I say, I think this is a general problem with confidence intervals, and applies just as much to CIs calculated for a grand mean. CIs calculated this way should be *calibrated*, in that they contain the true value 95% of the time, but other methods can give you more precise answers. Unfortunately, I don't know a better way of doing this with correlation coefficients, unlike grand means.

Comment: Interesting suggestion with the linear mixed model. I will think about that for a while. Thank you very much.