# Why do the confindence intervals overlap when my p-value is significant in meta-regression?

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I fitted a mixed effects meta-regression model with one dummy-coded predictor (USA vs. Europe).
The output tells me that the predictor is significant. I then wanted to get the average estimated effect size (and CI) for the US and for Europe. I used the predict() function. However when I look at the confidence intervals, they slightly overlap. Why is the p-value of the predictor in the meta-regression model significant, but the confidence intervals of the average effect size in each group overlap?

Comment: Also related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497338/why-is-mean-%C2%B1-2sem-95-confidence-interval-overlapping-but-the-p-value-is-0