# Which strategy to use to analyze my repeated measures data? SE clustered at evaluator level, or mixed-effects modelling?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, clustered-standard-errors

**I ran an experiment in which 104 people evaluated 12 ideas. I manipulated the source of the ideas to see if they influenced idea evaluation (internal vs. external).** **Each respondent evaluated all 12 ideas, and the 12 ideas appeared in the two conditions.**

I also have a second continuous IV (identity).

Now I need to analyze the data in R and I cannot decide which strategy is better:

**1. Mixed-effects modeling: Specifying the Respondent ID and the Idea as random effects using the lme4 package in R**

[image]

OR

**2. Standard errors clustered at the evaluator level with Respondent ID and Idea as fixed effects, using the lm_robust function in R.**

[image]