# Inconsistent Z-scores from multiple comparisons of factors in glmmadmb models

Tags: multiple-comparisons, glmm

First time poster, long time desperate reader. This place has been so helpful that I can usually find that someone has had the same problem as myself and had it answered here. However, I haven't found an answer to my problem below in a way that I understand.

I am having trouble finding consistent z-scores with `glmmadmb` when used in conjunction with `glht`. The z-scores attached to the reported p-values of a 6-level categorical variable match up with the p-values pinpointed on a z-table using the z-scores from the output of a glmmadmb model. But after a multiple comparisons, they do not. When testing a simpler 2-level factor the z-scores seem to be accurate for the original model and a multiple comparisons. Examples below. My query is three-fold:

1. I'm confused. Why is this happening?
2. Which test-statistic should I be reporting when using these comparisons?
3. How do I find the values of those test statistics?

I have been using glmmadmb (glmmADMB) to model bee visit duration (minutes) of bees to flowers with a categorical fixed factor (hour of morning: 6AM,7AM,8AM,9AM,10AM,11AM) and random factor (site). I chose to use a gamma distribution because the response variable is right-skewed, non-zero, and continuous. Code and output below:

```
sb<- glmmadmb(min~hour + (1|site), family = "gamma", data=sbsub)
summary(sb) 

Call:
glmmadmb(formula = min ~ hour + (1 | site), data = sbsub, family = "gamma")

AIC: 134 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    0.117      0.291    0.40  0.68708    
hour7         -0.794      0.322   -2.47  0.01363 *  
hour8         -1.112      0.315   -3.53  0.00042 ***
hour9         -0.642      0.323   -1.99  0.04660 *  
hour10        -1.178      0.311   -3.79  0.00015 ***
hour11         0.350      0.329    1.07  0.28646    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Number of observations: total=93, site=11 
Random effect variance(s):
Group=site
            Variance StdDev
(Intercept)   0.3774 0.6143

Gamma shape parameter: 1.4184 (std. err.: 0.19914)

Log-likelihood: -58.9969
```

The p-values in the output can be found in a z-table after using the listed z-score from the outputs and multiplying the z-table value by 2...But, I did not just want to see how bee visit duration at each hour compares to the base level of 6AM. I wanted to know how visit duration compares across all combinations of hours. So I used `glht` and `cld` from the `multcomp` package and got the output below. Looks sexy, and informative. I could plop those letters right on a bar chart.

```
sb2<-glht(sb, linfct = mcp(hour = "Tukey"))
summary(sb2)

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: glmmadmb(formula = min ~ hour + (1 | site), data = sbsub, family = "gamma")

Linear Hypotheses:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
7 - 6 == 0   -0.79358    0.32168  -2.467   0.1206   
8 - 6 == 0   -1.11241    0.31528  -3.528    <0.01 **
9 - 6 == 0   -0.64218    0.32272  -1.990   0.3215   
10 - 6 == 0  -1.17755    0.31065  -3.791    <0.01 **
11 - 6 == 0   0.35035    0.32868   1.066   0.8793   
8 - 7 == 0   -0.31883    0.44769  -0.712   0.9767   
9 - 7 == 0    0.15140    0.45244   0.335   0.9993   
10 - 7 == 0  -0.38398    0.44428  -0.864   0.9469   
11 - 7 == 0   1.14393    0.46486   2.461   0.1232   
9 - 8 == 0    0.47023    0.45019   1.044   0.8881   
10 - 8 == 0  -0.06515    0.44124  -0.148   1.0000   
11 - 8 == 0   1.46276    0.45547   3.212   0.0151 * 
10 - 9 == 0  -0.53537    0.43020  -1.244   0.7919   
11 - 9 == 0   0.99253    0.46182   2.149   0.2399   
11 - 10 == 0  1.52790    0.46197   3.307   0.0110 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

cld(sb2)
   6    7    8    9   10   11 
  "b" "ab"  "a" "ab"  "a"  "b"
```

But, these z-scores don't seem to mean anything. Looking them up in the z-table doesn't reveal the same p-value/2 in the output. So, reporting them seems moot. However, I feel I should report some kind of test-statistic to accompany the p-values? This also seems to happen when using `glmer` with a binomial distribution modeling predation and parasitism. In that case, the z-scores from a multiple comparisons between a 3-level categorical variable and a 2-level categorical variable do not have accurate z-scores.

I tried it with another smaller pollination model testing visit duration of bees in male and female flowers.

```
sb<- glmmadmb(min~sex + (1|site), family = "gamma", data=sbsub)
summary(sb)

Call:
glmmadmb(formula = min ~ sex + (1 | site), data = sbsub, family = "gamma")

AIC: 154.4 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   -0.154      0.257   -0.60    0.550  
sex1          -0.367      0.215   -1.71    0.087 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Number of observations: total=93, site=11 
Random effect variance(s):
Group=site
            Variance StdDev
(Intercept)   0.4517 0.6721

Gamma shape parameter: 1.102 (std. err.: 0.15293)

Log-likelihood: -73.1965 


sb2<-glht(sb, linfct = mcp(sex = "Tukey"))
summary(sb2)

Fit: glmmadmb(formula = min ~ sex + (1 | site), data = sbsub, family = "gamma")

Linear Hypotheses:
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
1 - 0 == 0  -0.3669     0.2147  -1.709   0.0875 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

cld(sb2)
   0    1    
  "a"  "a"
```

The p-values/2 in the output of both the original model and the multiple comparison can be found after using the listed z-score from the outputs to find a value in the z-table.

Not sure what's happening here. Any thoughts?

Much appreciated,
Nava

Comment: The $p$-values in the output of `glht` are meaningful and you can report them: The reported $p$-values are *adjusted for multiple comparison* (the output states it explicitly). In the last output, you only compare two groups and thus, the $p$-value has not to be adjusted.

Comment: Ok. The relationships reported to be different do look quite different, so that's good. How about the test-statistic, z?

Comment: What do you mean? The $z$-values are the estimates divided by the corresponding standard errors.

Comment: Ah-ha! I wasn't aware of that. I was double-checking the outputs with a z-table and they were not corresponding with the reported p-values. I assumed reviewers would do the same thing. In the cases where I am to report adjusted p-values from a multiple comparison, is it prudent to include the z-score as a test-statistic? Thanks for your help

Comment: You may want to have a look at [that](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56066/wald-test-in-regression-ols-and-glms-t-vs-z-distribution). Yes, I would include the $z$ or $t$ values as well as the adjusted $p$-values in a paper. The adjustment in multiple comparisons is a standard and reviewers should be aware of that. I would also state the adjustment procedure, which was "single-step" in this case. For technical details, see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/vignettes/multcomp-examples.pdf) on page 2 (the `pmv function). Please ask if you have further questions.

Comment: COOLSerdash, this brings peace to my mind.