# What is the z-value of glm model parameters?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, descriptive-statistics

I know what the z-value of a single observation is, that is explained in Wikipedia. But what is the z-value of a parameter in a glm model?

Comment: What exactly is Wikipedia's explanation?

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/60083/21054) or [this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56066/21054) can help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the test-statistic for the Wald-test that the parameter is 0. It is the parameter divided by the standard error. If the null-hypothesis is true (i.e. the parameter is 0 in the population) and we were to draw many samples from our population and compute the z-statistic in each of them, then those z-statistics will follow a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Well - they're asymptotically normal so for small sample sizes it might not quite be normal.